# Remove item from QListWidget on drag and drop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have two QListWidgets with items side by side. I would like to set events enabling

1. to remove item from list1 when it is dragged to list2
2. and vice versa

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListWidget, QHBoxLayout,QListWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys
import glob
import os


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.myListWidget1 = QListWidget()
        self.myListWidget2 = QListWidget()
        self.myListWidget1.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.myListWidget1.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.myListWidget2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.myListWidget2.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setGeometry(300, 350, 500, 300)
        self.myLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.myLayout.addWidget(self.myListWidget1)
        self.myLayout.addWidget(self.myListWidget2)

        os.chdir("./Downloads")
        for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
            QListWidgetItem(file, self.myListWidget1)

        self.setWindowTitle('Drag and Drop');
        self.setLayout(self.myLayout)

        self.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be set as [`defaultDropAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#defaultDropAction-prop) of the `QListWidget` in [`Qt::MoveAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DropAction-enum):

```py
self.myListWidget1.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
self.myListWidget2.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
```

Comment: It is good. But when I accidentally drag and drop in the same list, the item will vanish. It should stay on place.

Comment: @xralf If you drag and drop on the same QListWidget the item does not disappear but is placed at the end, from what I understand you want the position to be maintained after releasing if the QListWidget is the same, am I correct?

Comment: Try the second list. When you drop too early, the item will disappear.

Comment: @xralf No, I do not see that. 1) If the source and the destination are the same, only the movement of the items will be seen, 2) If the source and the destination are different, then the item will be moved to the destination being removed from the previous list. Linux , PyQt 5.14.1

Comment: I'm on Linux, PyQt 5.9.5

Comment: The code is added here `self.myListWidget2.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.myListWidget1.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.myListWidget2.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
`

Comment: @xralf What version of python3 do you use?

Comment: I use Python 3.6.9

Comment: @xralf what is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: I have used docker that has ubuntu 18.04 installed and install python3-pyqt5 that installs PyQt5 5.10.1 and I don't reproduce the problem. How did you install pyqt5?

Comment: with `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 ` It was the only possibility that worked for me.

Comment: I will try it tommorrow on Windows 10 and if it work there, it's sufficient for me.

Comment: @xralf As I said: Use docker with Ubuntu 18.04 and use the same command you indicate so we should have the same version of PyQt but you say you have PyQt5 5.9.5 and I PyQt5 5.10.1. Something is very strange

Comment: Yes, it's strange. I added a print button and it works now.

Comment: @xralf It is probably a bug of such an old version that you have.

Comment: Please, can I drag and drop multiple items. Do you know how? Thank you.